# PowerPoint + Matlab PasteSpecial (Alt+e+s)

Tags: matlab, powerpoint

I'm working on using MATLAB to produce an automated PowerPoint report. In order to be able to edit a MATLAB plot in PowerPoint we use PasteSpecial.

Manually, we use Copy Figure in the MATLAB figure and then Alt+e+s to PasteSpecial as an Enhanced Metafile into the PowerPoint file. This creates a group of objects we can manually edit. I would like to execute this PasteSpecial programmatically from MATLAB.

This link shows that you can do a PasteSpecial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.pastespecial

So I created MATLAB function to do the PasteSpecial (specifically PasteSpecial(2)) which works except that the pasted figure is a simple bitmap not a set of grouped objects we can edit.

From the referenced link I think I need something like PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile) but I can't find any way to access ppPasteEnhancedMetafile.

Note I'm doing this with just the base MATLAB not the Mathworks Toolbox. Also, I need the PasteSpecial not an alternative like create a figure, save as png, and insert because we want to be able to edit the figures in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 4):

This happens more than I'd like... when I construct a question for SO, I figure out the solution about 15 min after posting the question. AFTER I've spent hours previously trying various solutions and searching the web.

Turns out the problem is actually not my PasteSpecial line but how I copy the figure to the clipboard. Not doing this to get points but would like to make sure others don't have the same issue.

I was copying the figure to the clipboard via:

```
hgexport(fig_handle, '-clipboard')
```

I needed to be using:

```
print(fig_handle, '-clipboard', '-dmeta')
```

Then something like this works:

```
shapes_object.PasteSpecial(2)
```

where the shapes_object is a collection of shapes on a slide.

The requested MVCE:

```
%% Get a particular shape on a particular slide from a given Powerpoint presentation.
% Get the ActiveX Server for PowerPoint.
ppt = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');

% Open a PPTX file.
ppt.Presentations.Open(new_fname);

% Get the active PowerPoint Presentation. This also works if you
% manually open a PPTX file.
active_presentation = get(ppt, 'ActivePresentation');

% Get a list of Slide objects from PowerPoint.
slides = active_presentation.Slides;

% Get a particular Slide.
num_slides = slides.Count;
slide = slides.Item(i);      % i is valid between 1 and num_slides
slide.Select;                % Make this the active Slide.

% Get all the Shape on a Slide.
shapes = slide.Shapes;

% Get a specific shape from the Slide.
num_shapes = shapes.Count;
shape = shapes.Item(j);        % j is valid between 1 and num_shapes
shape.Select;                          % Make this the active Shape.

%% Plot a figure.
fig_handle = figure();
plot(rand(1, 1000), rand(1, 1000), 'r.')

% Note that PowerPoint's PasteSpecial pastes the figure into the middle of 
% the slide. In order to make it replace a Shape on the Slide you have to 
% change the new shape's position to be equal to the old shape's position.
% The first step in getting a figure to look better then we should reshape
% the figure.
fig_position = fig_handle.Position;
fig_position(3) = shape.Width;
fig_position(4) = shape.Height;
fig_handle.Position = fig_position;

% Copy the figure to the clipboard.
print(fig_handle, '-clipboard', '-dmeta')

%% Now paste the figure into the PowerPoint file.
pasted_shape = shapes.PasteSpecial(2)

% Change position and size.
pasted_shape .Top = shape.Top;
pasted_shape .Left = shape.Left;
pasted_shape s.Width = shape.Width;
pasted_shape .Height = shape.Height;

% Now delete the original shape.
shape.Delete;
```

**Context:**

I run simulations and wish to produce a standard PPT report for each run. I create a PPT file with a slide deck holding template slides. Each template slide is just that a template, I intend to replace every plot and all text programmatically from MATLAB. I use shapes.Item(j) to select and identify each shape manually. Then I build a class for each slide which holds a map of the Item number to a shape name like left_plot or plot_row1_col1.

I then create a report by aggregating the appropriate slide classes in the appropriate order. Then comes a lot of plot code and such to generate all of the plots necessary for each shape on each slide for the report.

Comment: As this may be helpful to a lot of others, could you post an entire MCVE? I.e., how do we create the required `shapes_object` instance in Matlab?

Comment: @Florian Done. Let me know if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Very cool! Didn't know this worked. Are you sure it's `shapes.objects` in the three lines where you select a specific one? My Matlab complains there. It works if I just just `shapes.Count` and `shapes.Item`.

Comment: @Florian Good catch. I was copying and pasting code from my tool. When I built the tool I was still figuring this out and was saving both the object and it's ID which is different from it's Item(#). Turns out I never use the ID. Anyways my original code saved the shape object to shapes.object and the IDs to shapes.map. When I posted the code here I manually changed shapes.object to just shapes but missed a couple. Should be all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MATLAB user. If, in the MATLAB VBA editor, you can add a reference to **Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library** (the number may change depending on what version you're using), then you should be able to use the ppPasteEnhancedMetafile parameter.
You might also try PasteSpecial(3) to see if it will paste a WMF.
Here's the enumeration page for PasteSpecial formats: [PpPasteDataType enumeration (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.pppastedatatype)

Comment: As so often happens when I construct a question for SO, I figured out the problem about 15 min later after spending hours previously trying various solutions. Turns out the problem is actually not my PasteSpecial line but how I copy the figure to the clipboard.

Comment: That makes sense, because PasteSpecial(2) should have been working. Glad you got it going.